# How do I sort(order) by enum list in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two columns to sort the entries by: `updated_at` and `state` (this is enum: `process`, `active`, `open`, `closed`)

If everything is clear from the `updated_at` column, you just need to set -> `orderBy('updated_at', 'desc)`

But how do I sort the enum list in this order: `open` -> `active` -> `closed`.

That is, first there would be open ones, then active ones, and then closed ones.

Could you help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a raw-SQL solution.

```
ORDER BY CASE state
    WHEN 'open' THEN 1
    WHEN 'active' THEN 2
    WHEN 'closed' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

This is a Laravel-based solution.

```
$query->orderByRaw("CASE state
    WHEN 'open' THEN 1
    WHEN 'active' THEN 2
    WHEN 'closed' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END");
```

Comment: Thank you, I really would like some Laravel Solution

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll try it!
Do you think there are any ways to avoid using order By Raw? I've never just used this filter

Comment: `Illuminate\Database` only exposes `orderBy()`, `orderByRaw()`, `orderByDesc()` methods to deal with `ORDER BY` clause. No other solution than this, I bet.

Comment: ok, thank you for explanation.
Could you explain me what does 'else 4' mean? All the others?

Comment: $projects = $projectsQuery
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->orderByRaw("CASE state
                                WHEN 'open' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'active' THEN 2
                                WHEN 'closed' THEN 3
                                ELSE 4
                                END")
            ->paginate(4); orderBy with orderByRaw doesn't work, why?

Comment: $projects = $projectsQuery
            ->orderByRaw("CASE state
                                WHEN 'Открытый' THEN 1
                                WHEN 'Активный' THEN 2
                                WHEN 'Закрытый' THEN 3
                                ELSE 4
                                END")
            ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
            ->paginate(4); This work! Weird...